# meaning of this infinitive

Tags: infinitives

> As night fell, the promised storm blew up around them. Spray from
>   the high waves splattered the walls of the hut and a fierce wind
>   rattled the filthy windows. Aunt Petunia found a few moldy blankets in
>   the second room and made up a bed for Dudley on the moth-eaten sofa.
>   She and Uncle Vernon went off to the lumpy bed next door, and **Harry
>   was left to find** the softest bit of floor he could and to curl up
>   under the thinnest, most ragged blanket. (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

There’s some vagueness in the sentence: (1) ‘left’ seems like a predicative complement for Harry, and ‘was to’ means ‘was obliged to’. (2) to-infinitive clause means the result of ‘was left’ –– Harry was left and he found ~. Which one is right or is there some meaning otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major dictionaries don't seem to do a good job covering this sense of *leave*, but *to leave [someone] to [do something]* means roughly "not to take care of [someone], such that he/she must [do something]". For example:

> […] his friend and lord had not kept him informed about these important events but instead had left him to fend for himself; left him to die, probably. [[link](http://books.google.com/books?id=4ci5Wd-V-kUC&pg=PA178&dq=left-him-to)]

> For a time he was left to find his own way, to set his own standards. [[link](http://books.google.com/books?id=xM0Aj-3x4-4C&pg=PA156&dq=left-to)]

Comment: Something like it is in OED at sense 5b: "With *obj.* and *inf.:* To allow (a person or thing) to do something, *to be* done or dealt with, without interference." But even that is not quite the same as **abandoning** someone and forcing them to do something on their own.